# How do I do tag_bind on all tags in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `TreeView` widget that I inserted a few items into, and applied a few tags selectively on some of those items. Now I want to bind a click event to all items in the widget, but the bind syntax looks like this:

```
treeView.tag_bind(tag_name, event_sequence, click_handler)
```

My problem is I want to do this for all tags, and also for non-tagged items. Is there something like `.tag_bind_all`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a list or function. Assuming to you want to bind all tags the same:

```
for this_tag in [tag_name1, tag_name2, tag_name3]:
    treeView.tag_bind(this_tag, event_sequence, click_handler)
```

Comment: This won't work because there are untagged items, and if I try to do `tag_bind` with an empty tag id `''` I match no items at all.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, this did it:

```
treeView.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', lambda *x:self.__treeViewItemSelected())
```

Then inside the method I can do :

```
item_id = treeView.focus()
value = treeView.item(item_id)
```